# Cannot pair my beats 3 bluetooth headset with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, headset

I have a Dell inspiron 7520 laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed. When I try to connect my beats 3 bluetooth headset via bluetooth settings, it prompts a message saying:

```
connection failed.
```

I tried to connect it with bluetooth manager software as well. But still cannot pair with the device. It identifies the device but fails to pair.

After issuing the command:

```
sudo pactl list short | grep blue -
```

The result I got was

```
7   module-bluetooth-policy     
8   module-bluetooth-discover       
9   module-bluez5-discover
```

Any suggestion. Please note that I recently switched to ubuntu from windows and the device was working fine with windows.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `pactl list short | grep blue`

Comment: Try using terminal `bluetoothctl` then `scan on` you should see a list of devices that are in pairing mode, find the MAC address of the audio device and try `pair` followed by the MAC address exactly as displayed in terminal

Comment: I had the same problem in Ubuntu 18.04 derivative with Powerbeats Pro; requirements section of this page helped me to solve. https://wiki.debian.org/BluetoothUser/a2dp

Answer (score 3):

I've just had the very same problem : my brand new Beats Solo 3 headset wouldn't pair with Bluetooth on my Aver Swift 3, with Ubuntu 20.04. I spent a morning reading help forums, installed Blueman, rebooted everything 5 times, and finally found a tip that solved everything in 2 minutes. In case it can help anyone :

1. Find the Bluetooth ID of your device (Blueman was helpful there, but any other Bluetooth manager works). If you don't have any I suggest :

```
user@computer:~$ sudo apt-get install blueman
```

then to lauch

```
user@computer:~$ blueman-manager
```

This opens a minimalist interface where you can identify at once the available Bluetooth devices. If your issue is not about detecting your device, you should see it with its ID (something like 56:D5:98:02:FF:9P). You can always try clicking on your device and selecting "pair", but for me it failed.

2. Open bluetoothctl

```
user@computer:~$ bluetoothctl
```

It should tell you something like

```
agent registered
[bluetooth]#
```

(if a device is already paired, its name is written instead of "bluetooth").

3. Run scan :

```
[bluetooth]# agent on
[bluetooth]# default-agent
[bluetooth]# scan on
```

This may take some time, and display some lines like this (new lines keep coming every now and then) :

```
Discovery started
[CHG] Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[NEW] Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[NEW] Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[bluetooth]#
```

My device wouldn't appear so I jumped to the next step, failed to pair, ran the scan again and this time it showed up.

4. When your device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX appears, you can interrupt the scan and attempt pairing. Before, set the device to trusted :

```
[bluetooth]# trust XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
changing XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# pair XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
attempting to pair with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[bluetooth]#
```

This may again take a while but should display eventually

```
[CHG] Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Connected: yes
Connection successful
[DeviceName]#
```

If it doesn't, then try again the steps authenticate - scan - trust - pair, perhaps switching your Bluetooth off and on too.

5. Select the right sound output in Parameters > Sound, and enjoy your fancy headset at last.

Hope this helps (I'm myself a beginner juste trying to explain what I stumbled by chance, so probably my tutorial is not top quality).

Answer (score 2):

Try executing the following commands:

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
sudo killall pulseaudio
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

Then, try to connect your device again using Blueman (Bluetooth Manager).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect beats devices to your Ubuntu system, then you’ll need to set up Bluetooth manager.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bluez bluez-tools
sudo apt install blueman
sudo reboot
```