# Beats Solo3 Bluetooth Headset connection

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, headset

I was trying to connect Beats solo3 headset with Ubuntu 18.04. I was able to see the headphone in the sound output settings, but not in the input. Is there any way I can configure the headset microphone to work with Ubuntu 18.04?

I tried to enable the profile HSP/HFP using bluetooth-manger but it's throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm picking on you because you're the most recent.

First off, I tried the solutions at [Cannot pair my beats 3 bluetooth headset with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/q/936876/253482) but they did not immediately work.

One problem I have with those answers (which are older) is that they require you to install third-party bluetooth device managers. Ubuntu 20.04+ already has `bluetoothctl`.

Another problem I have with them is that they didn't work.

Here's what worked:

1. Perform a full reset of the device you wish to pair (in this case, Beats Solo 3). (Hold down the power button for ~20 seconds.) *This will clear the paired devices list*.
2. Run

```
bluetoothctl paired-devices
```

—verify that your device is not listed. If it is, unpair the device with

```
bluetoothctl remove <MAC ID>
```

3. Now, perform a scan, like this:

```
celiyah@yoda-720:~$ bluetoothctl scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 11:22:33:44:55:66 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 12:34:56:78:9A:BC Neighbor's Television Set
[NEW] Device DE:F0:12:34:56:CE Chaim’s Beats Solo³
```

...there it is! You can hang up when you see it. `^C`

4. Connect to it:

```
bluetoothctl connect DE:F0:12:34:56:CE
```

...replace my contrived MAC ID with your own, of course.

Now you will be paired and connected!

Now, of course, you can also do the GUI after you reset the device, but it's harder to *remove* lingering devices (shakes fist at Settings UI folk). But this may just mean that it's harder to see it being done.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I guess in retrospect bluetoothctl is just bluez. For the record, my connection didn't hold even after this. I'll probably end up deleting it, but I might edit it later.