# How to undo 'sudo killall pulseaudio'?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, sudo

I ran the command

```bsh
sudo killall pulseaudio
```

because I read it here:

[Cannot pair my beats 3 bluetooth headset with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/a/1001186/1109106)

Now my sound doesn't work at all, when it was working before I ran this command.  How do I fix it?

Comment: Reboot computer

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the computer worked.

Answer (score 1):

This command should do.

```
$ pulseaudio -k
```

On the other hand,
I created a simple `bash script` that would fix my sound when something wrong occur.
This works on `Lubuntu 16.04 LTS`

```
#! /bin/bash

# removing pavucontrol config
cd ~/ && rm pavucontrol.ini && echo 'DONE: Removing pavucontrol.ini' || echo "FAILED: Removing pavucontrol.ini"

# removing pulse config
cd .config/ && rm -rf pulse/ && echo 'DONE: Removing pulse directory' || echo "FAILED: Removing pulse directory"

# restart pulse and alsa services
echo 'pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload' | bash
```