# Beats headset is detected, but can not be paired to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, headset

Recently I have been struggling to pair my beats studio3 headset to Ubuntu 20.04.

The headset works fine on my iphone, therefore I think it's a problem with Ubuntu, not the headset.

At first it was not even detected, however after I followed the instruction on [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1355914/1389460) link it got detected and was shown in the Bluetooth devices list, it still can't connect, and the toggle button seems to be locked.
[image]

As you can see, there isn't the yellow halo around the toggle button.

Also when I tried to pair it with `bluetoothctl`, after a long delay, it says the connection was canceled.

What is the possible cause, and how can I fix it?

**UPD:** I tried removing the device, however it is not again detected, and the instruction on the link doesn't work anymore.

**UPD2:** My laptops Bluetooth version is 5.1. I can't find my headsets Bluetooth version, but the model is beats studio 3 wireless.

Comment: BT version problem? Please add bluetooth version of the system and the bluetooth version of your headset.

Comment: 5.1 version is good enough and wont be the problem. Beats Studio 3 = 4.2

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with my Studio Buds.  Not sure if you've managed to solve this yet, so i'm adding this answer in case my solution works for you/anyone else looking this up.

First get the MAC Address of the headphones.  If your headphones are visible in the bluetooth settings (like in the screenshot) you can just copy from there.  Otherwise go into terminal and type `bluetoothctl`.  Then try to connect the studio buds like normal (lid open hold down button on case).  A MAC address should pop up on the screen.  You can verify that it's the headphones address with `info <address>` and it should show something like `Name: LE-Beats Studio Buds`

Now that you have the MAC address, in the terminal type `trust <address>` (wait for a message confirming its trusted), then while holding the case open type `pair <address>` (again wait for confirmation).  Finally type `connect <address>`.  Provided all 3 of these commands were successful your headset should now be paired.

A few things that worked for me:

1. Remove the headset FULLY from the bluetooth list THEN follow these steps.  This was sometimes necessary when it seemed like the pairing/connecting got "hung" up.
2. If the Bluetooth Settings "Remove Device" button isn't working, you can type `remove <address>` in the `bluetoothctl` window instead (this happened to me a few times when I was trying to figure out what was wrong)
3. This is a bit "on the nose" but try re-starting your computer and then following the steps above if none of that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with my Beats Flex. Not sure if you've managed to solve this yet, so I'm adding this answer in case my solution works for you/anyone else looking this up.

OS: ubuntu 20.04.04 LTS

- `sudo apt upgrade`
- Install Blueman: `sudo apt install bluez bluez-tools`
- `blueman-manager`
- Pair your headset

To enable my headset mic I've enabled Pipewire:
[https://atish3604.medium.com/solved-bluetooth-headset-mic-not-working-detected-in-ubuntu-20-04-86a5236444d0#:~:text=You%20need%20to%20uninstall%20ofono,if%20you%20have%20them%20installed.&text=If%20it's%20still%20not%20showing,check%20if%20it%20works%20now.][1]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Helped me connected my Beats Solo Pro to Ubuntu 22.04 on HP x360

Answer (score 0):

If you've used the headphones on other devices and use the noise reduction,
Make sure to set the normal configuration (without noise reduction).